# How do I switch a VC6 project to Unicode

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-c++-6

I need to switch a VC6 project to Unicode. In VS2008 there's a very convenient combo box that lets me choose between ANSI and Unicode build, but in VC6 I couldn't find such an obvious way to switch to Unicode.

Comment: Isn't this a good time to get a newer compiler?! This will be "porting" anyway.

Comment: @BoPersson I just like how VC6 doesn't grind my hard drive all the time :)   Anyway, this is a small project and I wouldn't get much benefit from VS2008 except Unicode by default.

Comment: It is just a #define.  Put it in your code or in the compiler setting (forgot its name).  You'll need #define UNICODE and #defined _UNICODE.

Comment: @Hans Thanks, that worked. I also got a linker error "msvcrtd.lib(crtexew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _WinMain@16", but I found how to fix it on [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/125750). Turns out I needed to redefine the entry point function to wWinMainCRTStartup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the solution as an answer. I needed to define _UNICODE as Hans said, and then I also needed to change the entry point function to wWinMainCRTStartup.